# How to fade in and out a CSS ":after" pseudo element when adding or removing a class

Tags: css, css-transitions

I know there are a lot of other questions on using transitions on CSS pseudo element but after going through a whole bunch of them I still can't get my scenario to work.

Basically, I want to add a class to an element, the class has a :after pseudo element with some content and a background. I'd like a fading effect on the :after element when adding or removing the class.

I've been trying this out in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/olakarlsson/W5e9Q/6/) and the code I have so far it this:

HTML

```
<div id="divA">Div test</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add it</button>
<button id="btnRemove">Take Away</button>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    background: red;
}

.test{
     background: blue;
}

.test:after{    
    background: #0c0;
    content: "Test";
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
  $("#divA").addClass("test");
});

$("#btnRemove").click(function() {
  $("#divA").removeClass("test");
});
```

Any help and hints would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forking @NilsKaspersson answer to make it work with your requirements.

Transition means from X to Y, you can't expect it to work with newly created attributes.

Then you have to create an initial attribute, and alter it later.

Since you don't want it to be there at the beginning, just use `color: transparent;` and `background: transparent;`

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hftbv/)</kbd>

Code:

```
div {
    width      : 200px;
    transition : all .5s linear;
    background : red;
}

div:after {
    transition : all .5s linear;
    background : transparent;
    color      : transparent;
    content    : "Test";
}

.test{
    background : blue;
}

.test:after{
    background : #0c0;
    color      : black;
}
```

Comment: The answers from Pandaiolo and NilsKaspersson where also very helpful but I'm marking this as the answer as it's the most complete answer covering my my case.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Changing answer based on new fiddle.

On most case, CSS transition must apply on already-defined properties.

Additionnaly, the changing of a pseudo `:after` element `content` will make the element be removed and re-added, which removes the said properties at the same time.

I have made a demo with animating the text `color` and `background-color` while pre-setting the `content`, so the properties are already present.

CSS :

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    background: red;
}
div:after {
    transition: all .5s linear;
    background: red;
    color: red;
    content: 'Test';
}
.test{
    background: blue;
}
.test:after{
    background: #0c0;
    color: black;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W5e9Q/10/

Comment: Your link is pointing into the mysterious lands of the files which hide and cannot be found.

Comment: Corrected the link :)

Comment: Sorry, I pointed to an old version of the fiddle, now fixed. The transition works on the background of the main div but not on the :after background and content, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here.

1.) `transition` only works when there's something to transition *from*. Since your `:after` element is essentially created when the class `test` is added to it, there's no transition going on.

2.) `transition` doesn't inherit, so you'll need to declare it once again on the pseudo element.

[Here's a quick n' dirty fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2yYv/).

I moved the generic rules for the pseudo element to the classless `div` and added a `transition` to it. Then when the class `test` is added to it, the background changes and it can transition from it's old value.

If you don't want the pseudo element's `content` to be visible all the time, consider hiding it with `opactiy: 0` and transition that to `1`, or use the `transparent` color value for `background` and/or `color`.

Comment: Please describe the changes you made or list the changed code, don't just say you forked it, even if it's implied that you changed it according to your observations.

Comment: I figured the two points made it clear enough. Added explaination.